# How does the DATABASE_ERR occur?

Tags: javascript, database, web-sql

Currently looking into various safeguards I can use to ensure that my database is being updated as expected and ways to handle the various errors that could occur in my app.

I am using javascript and websql.

The only issue is, there doesn't seem to be much in the way of documentation surrounding SQLError and the various errors that can occur.

I have found this: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#errors-and-exceptions which gives general descriptions of each of the errors, but for some, it leaves a lot to the imagination.

My question is, how does a DATABASE_ERR occur, or what could cause it?

Comment: `The statement failed for database reasons not covered by any other error code`

Answer (score 0):

Its a general purpose error that is thrown when the error is caused by something not covered by other cases. 
Typically, this would be something on the database server side. Say a lock on the file system, the operating system malfunctioning, etc.